# JQuery animate event responds slowly

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-animate

I made an evernt on JQuery which animates the change of height of my header when I scoll away from the top ( and reverse ).

The problem is that it responds slowly when going back on top. 
It has a small delay before it starts animating back to it's default position.
**The delay has nothing to do with the duration property.** The delay I'm talking about happens **before** the animation starts.
Thanks in advance.

```
    var $w = $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($w.scrollTop() > 0) {
        $("#header").animate({
          height: "66px",
          paddingTop: "16px"
        }, {
          duration: 30,
          easing: "linear",
        });     
    }
    else {
            $("#header").animate({
          height: "100px",
          paddingTop: "32px"
        }, {
          duration: 30,
          easing: "linear",
        });     
    }
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: You should debounce your scroll handler.  When you scroll down, you may get 100+ events, each of which need to complete before it can scroll up, but given that your animate is not based on relative position, it looks like it's not doing anything causing a "small" delay (depending on how many times you scrolled down and how quickly you scrolled back up).

Comment: @Nico How to remove the delay I described above.

Comment: @freedomn-m Currently on my html there is only a header. No other events to be completed.

Comment: Each time you scroll down, you get a scroll *event fired* (which is the event that you are handling). So if you scroll down 100px, that's (potentially, for arguments sake), *100 events fired* - each of which must run the 30ms animation before it can run the next.

Comment: Simplest: add a console.log to demonstrate:  `var $w = $(window).scroll(function() { console.log("scroll"); `

Comment: @freedomn-m I was completly unaware of this. Thank you a lot!